# OpenCv Image conversion

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv

When trying to do the watershed method i got this error:`Unsupported format or combination of formats (Only 32-bit, 1-channel output images are supported) in cvWatershed`

I think this is because my markers has 3 channels and a depth of 8. I think i need to convert this 3channel 8 depth image to a 32 bit 1 channel image. My question is am i right? and how do i do this conversion?

EDIT: Updated code with solutions

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package kitouch;

import org.OpenNI.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

/**
 *
 * @author olivierjanssens
 */
public class watherShedExample {


   // CanvasFrame frame5 = new CanvasFrame("Some T");
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
    CanvasFrame frame1 = new CanvasFrame("Foreground");
    CanvasFrame frame2 = new CanvasFrame("Dilated");
    CanvasFrame frame3 = new CanvasFrame("Background");
    CanvasFrame frame4 = new CanvasFrame("Markers");
    CanvasFrame frame5 = new CanvasFrame("Watershed");
        // Read input image
    IplImage image = cvLoadImage("/Users/olivierjanssens/Downloads/images/group.jpg");
    IplImage test = cvLoadImage("/Users/olivierjanssens/Downloads/images/binary.bmp");

    IplImage binary = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
     cvCvtColor(test, binary, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Eliminate noise and smaller objects, repeat erosion 6 times
    IplImage fg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), binary.depth(), binary.nChannels() /* channels */);
    cvErode(binary, fg, null /* 3x3 square */ , 6 /* iterations */);
    frame1.showImage(fg);


    // Identify image pixels pixels objects
    IplImage bg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), binary.depth(), binary.nChannels() /* channels */);
    cvDilate(binary, bg, null /* 3x3 square */ , 6 /* iterations */);
    frame2.showImage(bg);

    cvThreshold(bg, bg, 1 /* threshold */ , 128 /* max value */ , CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    frame3.showImage(bg);

    // Create marker image
    IplImage markers = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), IPL_DEPTH_8U, binary.nChannels() /* channels */);
    cvAdd(fg, bg, markers, null);
    frame4.showImage(markers);
/*
     * TEST SOLUTION 1
    IplImage gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(markers), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
    cvCvtColor(markers, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    IplImage img32bit1chan = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    double ve;
    for (int i = 0; i < gray.width(); i++) // markers width
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < gray.height(); j++) // markers height
       {
           ve = cvGetReal2D((IplImage)gray, j, i); 
           cvSetReal2D((IplImage)img32bit1chan , i, j, ve);
       }
    }
*/

    //SOLUTION 2 
    IplImage markers32f = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), IPL_DEPTH_32F, binary.nChannels());
    cvConvertScale(markers, markers32f, 1, 0); // converts from IPL_DEPTH_8U to IPL_DEPTH_32F


    cvWatershed(image, markers32f);

    frame5.showImage(image);

    }
}
```

Comment: How many channels `image` and `binary` has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual conversion would look something like the following (haven't tested the code):

```
IplImage gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(markers), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
cvCvtColor(markers, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

IplImage img32bit1chan = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray), IPL_DEPTH_32S, 1);

// convert 8-bit 1-channel image to 32-bit 1-channel
cvConvertScale(gray, img32bit1chan , 1/255.);

cvWatershed(image, img32bit1chan);
```

Comment: Hi , there's a problem. cvGetReal2D only supports single-channel arrays. And the image has 3 channels.

Comment: I tried converting the coloured image to gray. But the mat32bit1chan has depth 5 and i can't see the nchannels. I added the code that you suggested to the question. Maybe you can see a mistake in it ? (Btw it is the marker that has to be 32bit 1chan, though it is also a 8bit 3 chan image , so nothing changes.)

Comment: Ok i did exactly as you said (edited in the question for your confirmation). Though it is the markers that needs to be 32bit 1 chan ... so i don't see why i'm doing this with image :S.

Comment: I tried your updated code, but still got an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: /Users/olivierjanssens/source/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:1797: error: (-211) index is out of range in function cvPtr2D

 at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvSetReal2D(Native Method)
 at kitouch.watherShedExample.main(watherShedExample.java:75). I thought this would work tbh :p

Comment: No more errors. but i did change this : cvConvertScale(gray, img32bit1chan , 1/255,0); I expected a different output though... my image just got brighter. That's all

Comment: Well, the error stated in your question was solved. Now you got another problem to deal with, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Java API, but here is how you might go about it:

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("/Users/olivierjanssens/Downloads/images/group.jpg");

// this will force the image to be read as grayscale (i.e. single channel)
// sometimes saving a "binary" bitmap will result in a 3 channel image
IplImage binary = cvLoadImage("/Users/olivierjanssens/Downloads/images/binary.bmp", 0);

...

IplImage markers = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), IPL_DEPTH_8U, binary.nChannels() /* channels */);
cvAdd(fg, bg, markers, null);
frame4.showImage(markers);

IplImage markers32f = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binary), IPL_DEPTH_32F, binary.nChannels());
cvConvertScale(markers, markers32f, 1, 0); // converts from IPL_DEPTH_8U to IPL_DEPTH_32F

cvWatershed(image, markers32f);
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: I got this error when converting:


: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels()) in cvConvertScale, file /Users/olivierjanssens/source/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 1193
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: /Users/olivierjanssens/source/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:1193: error: (-215) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function cvConvertScale

 at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvConvertScale(Native Method)
 at kitouch.watherShedExample.main(watherShedExample.java:65)

Comment: That means the sizes or number of channels are different between `markers` and `markers32f`. What are the sizes and number of channels of these two images on the `cvConvertScale` line?

Comment: Try replacing all the `binary.nChannels()` with `1`. This will ensure that the number of channels is the same.

Comment: @karlphillip That's what I'm guessing too :)

Comment: Binary has 3 channels and 8 bits , so apparently no

Comment: I tried it again with the conversion to grayscale. So i did : IplImage test = cvLoadImage("/Users/olivierjanssens/Downloads/images/binary.bmp");

    IplImage binary = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
     cvCvtColor(test, binary, CV_BGR2GRAY);

at the start. But still the : 'Only 32-bit, 1-channel output images are supported) in cvWatershed' error remains

Comment: When i look at the markers32f it has 32 bit and 1 channel. The image has 8 bits and 3 channels. When i look at the documentation this is correct: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm. But i still get the error previously mentioned :S. I updated my code in the question.